# Kendo/MVC upload - Maximum request length exceeded

Tags: asp.net, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I still get the error even if I have increased the limits as shown below.
I am using vs2013, MVC5 and Windows 8.1

```
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
 </system.web>

<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>


<handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```